# Is it ok to ask questions about mythicism, the notion that Jesus did not exist?

Tags: discussion

I asked this on meta.christianity.SE; they suggested my question is not appropriate for that forum and sent me here.

I am trying to find a reason to take seriously the notion that Richard Carrier and a few other experts can refute the consensus among biblical scholars -- Bart Ehrman has said that no one teaching in any college or university in any related field in the western world in doubts the existence of the man Jesus. I'm not trying to start an argument. I'm just trying to satisfy my curiosity.

Comment: Maybe just ask the question: did Jesus exist historical? Although I think it may have already been asked.

Comment: Migrated from main. I've also deleted the "answers" to the (actually yet unasked) main question.

Comment: @T.E.D. Wow, did I post this to the main history.SE? I'm really sorry, I intended it for meta. Thanks for moving it.

Comment: That's what I'm here for. I will say that it had only one close vote (probably due to it belonging here), and 2 answers with a total of 4 upvotes when I found it. That probably should answer your meta question. :-)

Comment: Can anyone site archeological evidence of the existence of the man Jesus?

Comment: For some reason, it is still being displayed in new/active tabs of main HSE. Don't know if that's normal or a bug.

Comment: On Skeptics.SE is "[Did Jesus live?](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1624/did-jesus-live)" which addresses the question in question.